# Post-Invoke-Success if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/

Tags: apt, updates

When I ran `sudo apt update` I got this error.

```
Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success  
'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; 
then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'     
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

[image: Post-Invoke-Success if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/]

I have searched it on Google and found nothing the same thing.
Before that I changed my repository to http://kambing.ui.ac.id.